# How to handle multiple log4net configurations?

Tags: logging, log4net, log4net-configuration

I am using one utility dll which is internally using log4net and it's version is 1.2.10.0, currently i am trying implement logging using log4net version 1.2.13.0. When i am running the program it is throwing below error

```
Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b44e1d426115821' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040
```

After this i refered log4net, Version=1.2.10.0 in my application but it started logging the things which are written in utility dll also. 
How to solve this problem to get only my application log details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the logger names used by the utility dll are consistent, then just override them in your config to suppress all logging:

```
<logger name="Utility.Dll.Logger.Name" additivity="false">
    <level value="OFF" />        
</logger>
```

If this isn't practical, you can isolate your configuration from the other DLL by using a [custom repository](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/repositories.html).

Comment: By doing this can i use new version of the log4net?